# Convert a flat datastructure into a tree

Tags: perl, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have an array of hashes.  Each element in the array is a node in a hierarchical tree and has referential data for who the parent is.  I will have thousands and hundreds of thousands of nodes in the tree... essentially an unknown set of nodes has to be converted to JSON (shown below) for use with http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

UPDATE:  position_id is a node in the heretical tree.  placement_id is the parent's position_id (adjacency referential tree).

UPDATE: Here's the full AoH Data::Dumper result with Nested Set and Adjacency result from a modified version of [DBIx::Tree::NestedSet](http://search.cpan.org/~djcp/DBIx-Tree-NestedSet-0.16/lib/DBIx/Tree/NestedSet.pm) (custom).

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'lft' => '673',
            'id' => '109',
            'date_created' => '2015-08-15',
            'level' => '7',
            'user_id' => '13',
            'placement_id' => '11',
            'position_id' => '13',
            'status' => '1',
            'structure_id' => '1',
            'rght' => '684'
          },
          {
            'placement_id' => '13',
            'position_id' => '22',
            'status' => '1',
            'structure_id' => '1',
            'rght' => '679',
            'lft' => '674',
            'date_created' => '2015-08-15',
            'id' => '116',
            'level' => '8',
            'user_id' => '22'
          },
          {
            'user_id' => '101',
            'level' => '9',
            'id' => '200',
            'date_created' => '2015-08-15',
            'lft' => '675',
            'rght' => '676',
            'structure_id' => '1',
            'status' => '1',
            'position_id' => '101',
            'placement_id' => '22'
          },
          {
            'date_created' => '2015-08-15',
            'id' => '201',
            'level' => '9',
            'user_id' => '374',
            'lft' => '677',
            'structure_id' => '1',
            'rght' => '678',
            'placement_id' => '22',
            'position_id' => '374',
            'status' => '1'
          },
          {
            'lft' => '680',
            'user_id' => '95',
            'level' => '8',
            'id' => '117',
            'date_created' => '2015-08-15',
            'status' => '1',
            'position_id' => '95',
            'placement_id' => '13',
            'rght' => '681',
            'structure_id' => '1'
          }
        ];
```

THIS IS THE GOAL, For this example I need to end up with:

```
{
    "name": "13",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "22",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "101"
                },
                {
                    "name": "374"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "95"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also see the format I am trying to arrive at here (minus size): 
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033#flare.json

My failed approach(es) included various attempts at looping through the array of hashes to create a recursive Hash of Hashes that can then be used with the [JSON Perl module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) to create the actual JSON I need.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108400/perl-two-column-flat-file-to-a-complex-unordered-list-tree

Comment: If the first hash had level 1 instead of level 7, how would it then look like?

Comment: It would look the same.  The level itself is the overall level within the greater tree.  So, 13 is level 7 of the overall tree, but level 1 of this group.

Comment: @melpomene I think it's only distantly related as the solution of that question takes DATA and creates an array of hashes.  I have an array of hashes that I need to make into a HOH.

Comment: @Mel 1) You don't have an array of hashes, you have data (a list of records represented as a JSON string). The other question had a list of records represented as lines with tab-separated fields. 2) What do you mean, "creates an array of hashes"? I don't see an AoH there.

Comment: @melpomene  Right above the JSON data I wrote  "This is a sample array of hashes (shown in JSON):"  Each JSON line is an array element, each element is a HASH (key,value pair)... which I just happen to show you via a JSON representation.  I have that data in an AoH, and need to get it into an HoH that I can then use JSON.pm to create the needed data format.

Comment: @melpomene 2) From that example:   "push @{$underlings_of{$mgr}}, $emp;"  Creating an AoH in the while loop.

Comment: @Mel what does placement_id mean? Is it important?

Comment: @jan_kowalski_314 Yes, see update.  "position_id is a node in the tree. placement_id is the parent's position_id (adjacency referential tree)."

Comment: The following question while more generic than mine is essentially asking the same question.  I think the final solution I presented answers his question nicely.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884260/generate-json-from-nested-sets-perl-sql-jquery

Comment: @Mel That's a hash of arrrays, not an array of hashes.

Comment: @RedSands: In future, please do not edit the solution into your question; either accept the answer which provided that solution, or post your own answer to your question.

Comment: @matt Valid point.  Since you can see that I am some what new to stackoverflow, would you help me understand?  The solution presented was close but not 100%.  It started out with some bugs, had no explanation, and wasn't complete.  So, I posted adapted versions within edits to solicit a better answer.  In the end I accepted his answer, but added a few additional things that I believe would be very helpful should anyone else want to read this question and answer in the future.  To be clear: are you saying that I should do that as my own answer?  If so, okay... but, that seems odd. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $data = [
   {  position_id => 123, placement_id => undef },
   {  position_id => 456, placement_id => 123 },
   {  position_id => 789, placement_id => 123 },
   # ...
];

my $roots;
{
   my %recs_by_name;
   my %children_by_parent_name;
   for my $row (@$data) {
      my $name        = $row->{position_id};
      my $parent_name = $row->{placement_id};

      my $rec = {
         name => $name,
      };

      push @{ $children_by_parent_name{$parent_name // 'root'} }, $rec;
      $recs_by_name{$name} = $rec;
   }

   $roots = delete($children_by_parent_name{root}) || [];

   for my $name (keys(%children_by_parent_name)) {
      my $children = $children_by_parent_name{$name};
      if ( my $rec = $recs_by_name{$name} ) {
         $rec->{children} = $children;
      } else {
         die("Parent $name doesn't exist.\n");
         push @$roots, @$children;
      }
   }
}

print(Dumper($roots));
```

Tested.

You appear to have the depth of each node available to you (`level`). Simpler code could be used if your data was sorted by increasing depths.

Comment: Walk me through your approach please  You provide no explanation.  Not sure who down voted your answer, or why exactly.  However, your answer isn't helpful and seems to have issues, but I'll let you explain.

Comment: Each line is self-contained, so I'm not sure what there is to explain. Which part do you need help with?

Comment: The 'children' key isn't being created to have a full nested HOH.  See Edit.

Comment: I think a while needs to be part of the solution as there will be even potentially thousands of levels within the tree.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Mel, You dumped `\%children_by_parent_name` when you should have dumped `$roots`. I thought it was obvious since it's the only variable that exists at the end of the code, but I made it even more obvious.

Comment: Tested. Fixed two bugs.

Comment: Those fixes solved my issue.  We do have other attributes as well, including level.  How might those be added ad additional attributes in the JSON?  like {"name": "13", "level": 7, "children": []},

Comment: i don't know why you keep saying JSON since your question has nothing to do with JSON. If you want to add stuff to the records, add stuff to the records.

Comment: My questions has everything to do with JSON.  From the start, I needed to get data into a format I could pass to JSON.pm.  Thanks for your assistance.  My question was "How might those records be added?"

Comment: No, your question is about getting the data into a specific format. The fact that you will pass that data structure to `encode_json` is irrelevant. // Re: 'My question was "How might those records be added?"' huh? What records? Added to what?

Comment: A satisfactory answer would have also included going directly from the data I had... to a JSON format.  REREAD my questions  "essentially an unknown set of nodes has to be converted to JSON".  JSON was ALWAYS the point.  To simply narrow in on what you felt was important shows that you were less interested in what my question ACTUAL was (via also changing the title... to something 100% incorrect).

Comment: Not so. It doesn't change the answer at all whether you save the data structure using JSON, YAML, XML or something else.  As such, it's irrelevant and off-topic that you save the data structure using JSON, YAML, XML or something else. Contrary to what you claim, I didn't decide this; you did when you said which structure you wanted to end up with. Learn to keep your questions limited to problem at hand. Speaking of the title, I made a typo. Fixing it..

Comment: Are you saying you also have problem encoding a data structure using JSON? If so, that's a separate problem, and should be a separate question. Show your effort, and clearly state what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

While it was @ikegami who ultimately answered the question that led to the solution.  I believe the following adaptation adds 4 important elements/clarifications I found helpful, and thought others reading this question and answer would also find useful.

1- Clear addition of all key,value pairs from the originating AoH to the resulting HOH.  See while loop.

2- A Child node counter.

3- Inclusion and use of the encode_json function from [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm)

4- The result is also an Array with a Hash as the first element.  Newbies (like me) might find the explicit @{$roots}[0] passed to encode_json as helpful.

At first I had a similar adapted solution posted as an UPDATE within my question, but was admonished that it was bad etiquette and instructed to post an answer.

@ikegami's deserves the credit for the core of the solution.

```
sub get_jsonTree {
    my ($array_of_hashes_ref) = @_;

    my $roots;
    my %recs_by_name;
    my %children_by_parent_name;
    my %count;
    for my $row (@$array_of_hashes_ref) {
        my $name        = $row->{position_id};
        my $parent_name = $row->{placement_id};

        my $rec = {
            name => $name,
        };

        ## Added to loop through all key,value pairs and add them to $rec
        while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%$row) ) {
            $rec->{$key} = $value;
        }

        ##Added To Count Child Nodes
        $count{$parent_name} = 0 if (!$count{$parent_name});        
        $rec->{'child_count'} = $count{$parent_name};
        $count{$parent_name}++;

        push @{ $children_by_parent_name{$parent_name // 'root'} }, $rec;
        $recs_by_name{$name} = $rec;
    }

    $roots = delete($children_by_parent_name{root}) || [];

    for my $name (keys(%children_by_parent_name)) {
        my $children = $children_by_parent_name{$name};
        if ( my $rec = $recs_by_name{$name} ) {
            $rec->{children} = $children;
        } else {
            $util{'test'} .=  "Parent $name doesn't exist.\n<BR>";
            push @$roots, @$children;
        }
    }

    use JSON;
    my $json_str = encode_json(@{$roots}[0]);

    return $json_str;
}

my $array_of_hashes_ref = [
    {  position_id => 123, placement_id => undef },
    {  position_id => 456, placement_id => 123 },
    {  position_id => 789, placement_id => 123 },
    # ...
];

my $json_str = &get_jsonTree($array_of_hashes_ref);
```